# ejabberd and Push Notification

Tags: iphone, xmpp, apple-push-notifications, ejabberd, google-cloud-messaging

I have integrate chat system in my iOS and Android app using XMPP. I have used ejabberd 2 in the server side. Chatting sytem works fine. I want to integrate push notification in my chating using APNS and GCM. How can I send a push notification with each chat message ? ejabberd 2 has any API or extensions available to implement this feature ?

Help is highly appreciable,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please use the below blog , it is very simple and useful, it is works fine for me.

http://symmetricinfinity.com/2013/01/23/ios-push-notifications-from-ejabberd.html

Comment: how are pushing to android offline user ?

Comment: How to send FCM configuration param to eJabberD from Android client ? I'm using Smack SDK client side. Any suggestion @Mickaël Rémond, vks

Answer (score 8):

There is no ejabberd plugin for apns or gcm. I think you have two main options here:

1. Use `mod_offline_post` module which will send `POST` request on given url. Then you can use any existing backend language to process both apns and gcm (I am using rails as backend anyway so this is only one more enpoint to handle it).
2. Based on `mod_offline_post`, create your own module which will send push notifications instead of `POST` request. There are few examples and libraries which implements apns and gcm. I.e. [apns4erl](https://github.com/inaka/apns4erl) for apns and [this code](http://tiliman.wordpress.com/2013/01/02/google-cloud-messaging-with-erlang/) for gcm. But for that of course it would be good to know some erlang.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there is no public ejabberd module that provides an interface to GCM or APN.

I suggest you to implement a custom module with an [ejabberd_hook](http://www.ejabberd.im/Events%20and%20hooks). You can see an example of ejabberd internal module and presence hook [here](http://metajack.im/2008/08/28/writing-ejabberd-modules-presence-storms/).

If you want to forward messages to offline users I suggest `offline_message_hook` while for a generic filtering of messages I suggest `filter_packet({From, To, Packet})` and check for packet type (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939879/how-to-filter-messages-in-ejabberd) stackoverflow question).

Knowing the recipient you can retrieve from the db the device token/registration id and forward the message using some erlang code.

For APN take a look at some [simple code](http://bravenewmethod.wordpress.com/2011/02/16/apple-push-notifications-with-erlang/) explaining how it works or to this erlang [ex_apns](https://github.com/extend/ex_apns). If you want more information about APN of if you want a mock server for APN you can read this blog [post](http://pdincau.wordpress.com/2013/04/01/a-mock-apn-server-in-erlang/).

For an example of GCM you can use the example link provided by @Lucas.

Comment: How can I retrieve device token from db ?

Comment: this depends totally upon how you store tokens and on what db.