# building, authenticating, and parsing with the Smack library

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to connect to Firebase Cloud Messaging by using smack library.
I don't have much knowledge of the Smack API. After reading the Firebase docs, I see that the connection must be authenticated and there are a series of responses back and forth between "app server" and Cloud Connection Servers. According to the docs, I must create a Sasl Plain authentication. I don't know how to implement this. But after reading some posts by other StackOverFlow users I see that I must create an authentication class. Specifically, I was reviewing the answers and comments on "Gtalk XMPP SASL authentication failed using mechanism X-OAUTH2?" These responses that are between CCS and the "app server" are enclosed in  and  tags. I dont know how to use Smack to get or build these responses. I do have my connection set up with XMPP, and I've tried setting a addAsyncStanzListener to my XMPP connection with the hopes of getting some of these responses from CCS. But, nothing comes in. The responses between "app server" and CCS could be found in this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#connecting

Does anyone here know how to proceed from here. I think that Smack is not well documented and having little knowledge of XMPP makes it even worse. There are all these classes, Packets, extensions, IQ class, XML pull parsers etc.

Any rough structure on the set up would be ideal.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet of my server code that I use with Firebase. If you want to understand in more detail try this blog post (it is how I figured out how to get everything to work in the end): http://www.grokkingandroid.com/xmpp-server-google-cloud-messaging/

In order to get the code below to work you will need to go to the Firebase console and go to project settings

[image]

From here you will need to take note of your Server Key and Sender ID and replace it in the code snippet below (it is near the bottom of the code) and save it in your path as SmackCcsClient.class
[image]

After doing that you can compile and run your server through the command promt:

```
// Set up java file (replace PATH_TO_WHERE_YOUR_CLASS_IS with your own path and make sure to put the json and smack JARs there as well
javac -d PATH_TO_WHERE_YOUR_CLASS_IS -sourcepath src -cp PATH_TO_WHERE_YOUR_CLASS_IS\json-simple-1.1.1.jar;PATH_TO_WHERE_YOUR_CLASS_IS\smack-3.4.1-0cec571.jar PATH_TO_WHERE_YOUR_CLASS_IS\SmackCcsClient.java

// Run 
java -cp PATH_TO_WHERE_YOUR_CLASS_IS;PATH_TO_WHERE_YOUR_CLASS_IS\json-simple-1.1.1.jar;PATH_TO_WHERE_YOUR_CLASS_IS\smack-3.4.1-0cec571.jar SmackCcsClient
```

/*

SmackCcsClient:

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketInterceptor;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.PacketTypeFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.DefaultPacketExtension;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Packet;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.PacketExtension;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.provider.PacketExtensionProvider;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.provider.ProviderManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.StringUtils;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.io.*;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

/**
 * Sample Smack implementation of a client for GCM Cloud Connection Server.
 *
 * For illustration purposes only.
 */
public class SmackCcsClient {

    static final String REG_ID_STORE = "gcmchat.txt";   

    static final String MESSAGE_KEY = "SM";
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("SmackCcsClient");

    public static final String GCM_SERVER = "fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com";
    public static final int GCM_PORT = 5235;

    public static final String GCM_ELEMENT_NAME = "gcm";
    public static final String GCM_NAMESPACE = "google:mobile:data";

    static Random random = new Random();
    XMPPConnection connection;
    ConnectionConfiguration config;

    /**
     * XMPP Packet Extension for GCM Cloud Connection Server.
     */
    class GcmPacketExtension extends DefaultPacketExtension {
        String json;

        public GcmPacketExtension(String json) {
            super(GCM_ELEMENT_NAME, GCM_NAMESPACE);
            this.json = json;
        }

        public String getJson() {
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        public String toXML() {
            return String.format("<%s xmlns=\"%s\">%s</%s>", GCM_ELEMENT_NAME,
                    GCM_NAMESPACE, json, GCM_ELEMENT_NAME);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public Packet toPacket() {
            return new Message() {
                // Must override toXML() because it includes a <body>
                @Override
                public String toXML() {

                    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
                    buf.append("<message");
                    if (getXmlns() != null) {
                        buf.append(" xmlns=\"").append(getXmlns()).append("\"");
                    }
                    if (getLanguage() != null) {
                        buf.append(" xml:lang=\"").append(getLanguage())
                                .append("\"");
                    }
                    if (getPacketID() != null) {
                        buf.append(" id=\"").append(getPacketID()).append("\"");
                    }
                    if (getTo() != null) {
                        buf.append(" to=\"")
                                .append(StringUtils.escapeForXML(getTo()))
                                .append("\"");
                    }
                    if (getFrom() != null) {
                        buf.append(" from=\"")
                                .append(StringUtils.escapeForXML(getFrom()))
                                .append("\"");
                    }
                    buf.append(">");
                    buf.append(GcmPacketExtension.this.toXML());
                    buf.append("</message>");
                    return buf.toString();
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public SmackCcsClient() {
        // Add GcmPacketExtension
        ProviderManager.getInstance().addExtensionProvider(GCM_ELEMENT_NAME,
                GCM_NAMESPACE, new PacketExtensionProvider() {

                    @Override
                    public PacketExtension parseExtension(XmlPullParser parser)
                            throws Exception {
                        String json = parser.nextText();
                        GcmPacketExtension packet = new GcmPacketExtension(json);
                        return packet;
                    }
                });
    }

    /**
     * Returns a random message id to uniquely identify a message.
     *
     * <p>
     * Note: This is generated by a pseudo random number generator for
     * illustration purpose, and is not guaranteed to be unique.
     *
     */
    public String getRandomMessageId() {
        return "m-" + Long.toString(random.nextLong());
    }

    /**
     * Sends a downstream GCM message.
     */
    public void send(String jsonRequest) {
        Packet request = new GcmPacketExtension(jsonRequest).toPacket();
        connection.sendPacket(request);
    }

    /**
     * Handles an upstream data message from a device application.
     *
     * <p>
     * This sample echo server sends an echo message back to the device.
     * Subclasses should override this method to process an upstream message.
     */
    public void handleIncomingDataMessage(Map<String, Object> jsonObject) {

        String from = jsonObject.get("from").toString();

        // PackageName of the application that sent this message.
        String category = jsonObject.get("category").toString();

        // Use the packageName as the collapseKey in the echo packet
        String collapseKey = "echo:CollapseKey";
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, String> payload = (Map<String, String>) jsonObject
                .get("data");



            String messageText = payload.get("message_text");
            String messageFrom = payload.get("message_userfrom");
            String messageTime = payload.get("message_timestamp");
            String toUser = payload.get("message_recipient");

            payload.put("message_text", messageText);
            payload.put("message_userfrom", messageFrom);           
            payload.put("message_timestamp", messageTime);

            String message = createJsonMessage(toUser, getRandomMessageId(),
                    payload, collapseKey, null, false);
            send(message);

    }

    /**
     * Handles an ACK.
     *
     * <p>
     * By default, it only logs a INFO message, but subclasses could override it
     * to properly handle ACKS.
     */
    public void handleAckReceipt(Map<String, Object> jsonObject) {
        String messageId = jsonObject.get("message_id").toString();
        String from = jsonObject.get("from").toString();
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "handleAckReceipt() from: " + from
                + ", messageId: " + messageId);
    }

    /**
     * Handles a NACK.
     *
     * <p>
     * By default, it only logs a INFO message, but subclasses could override it
     * to properly handle NACKS.
     */
    public void handleNackReceipt(Map<String, Object> jsonObject) {
        String messageId = jsonObject.get("message_id").toString();
        String from = jsonObject.get("from").toString();
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "handleNackReceipt() from: " + from
                + ", messageId: " + messageId);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a JSON encoded GCM message.
     *
     * @param to
     *            RegistrationId of the target device (Required).
     * @param messageId
     *            Unique messageId for which CCS will send an "ack/nack"
     *            (Required).
     * @param payload
     *            Message content intended for the application. (Optional).
     * @param collapseKey
     *            GCM collapse_key parameter (Optional).
     * @param timeToLive
     *            GCM time_to_live parameter (Optional).
     * @param delayWhileIdle
     *            GCM delay_while_idle parameter (Optional).
     * @return JSON encoded GCM message.
     */
    public static String createJsonMessage(String to, String messageId,
            Map<String, String> payload, String collapseKey, Long timeToLive,
            Boolean delayWhileIdle) {
        Map<String, Object> message = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        message.put("to", to);
        if (collapseKey != null) {
            message.put("collapse_key", collapseKey);
        }
        if (timeToLive != null) {
            message.put("time_to_live", timeToLive);
        }
        if (delayWhileIdle != null && delayWhileIdle) {
            message.put("delay_while_idle", true);
        }
        message.put("message_id", messageId);
        message.put("data", payload);
        return JSONValue.toJSONString(message);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a JSON encoded ACK message for an upstream message received from
     * an application.
     *
     * @param to
     *            RegistrationId of the device who sent the upstream message.
     * @param messageId
     *            messageId of the upstream message to be acknowledged to CCS.
     * @return JSON encoded ack.
     */
    public static String createJsonAck(String to, String messageId) {
        Map<String, Object> message = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        message.put("message_type", "ack");
        message.put("to", to);
        message.put("message_id", messageId);
        return JSONValue.toJSONString(message);
    }

    /**
     * Connects to GCM Cloud Connection Server using the supplied credentials.
     *
     * @param username
     *            GCM_SENDER_ID@gcm.googleapis.com
     * @param password
     *            API Key
     * @throws XMPPException
     */
    public void connect(String username, String password) throws XMPPException {
        config = new ConnectionConfiguration(GCM_SERVER, GCM_PORT);
        config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.enabled);
        config.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
        config.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(false);
        config.setSendPresence(false);
        config.setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());

        // NOTE: Set to true to launch a window with information about packets
        // sent and received
        config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);

        // -Dsmack.debugEnabled=true
        XMPPConnection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;

        connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
        connection.connect();

        connection.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
                logger.info("Reconnecting..");
            }

            @Override
            public void reconnectionFailed(Exception e) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Reconnection failed.. ", e);
            }

            @Override
            public void reconnectingIn(int seconds) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Reconnecting in %d secs", seconds);
            }

            @Override
            public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Connection closed on error.");
            }

            @Override
            public void connectionClosed() {
                logger.info("Connection closed.");
            }
        });

        // Handle incoming packets
        connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {

            @Override
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Received: " + packet.toXML());
                Message incomingMessage = (Message) packet;
                GcmPacketExtension gcmPacket = (GcmPacketExtension) incomingMessage
                        .getExtension(GCM_NAMESPACE);
                String json = gcmPacket.getJson();
                try {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    Map<String, Object> jsonObject = (Map<String, Object>) JSONValue
                            .parseWithException(json);

                    // present for "ack"/"nack", null otherwise
                    Object messageType = jsonObject.get("message_type");

                    if (messageType == null) {
                        // Normal upstream data message
                        handleIncomingDataMessage(jsonObject);

                        // Send ACK to CCS
                        String messageId = jsonObject.get("message_id")
                                .toString();
                        String from = jsonObject.get("from").toString();
                        String ack = createJsonAck(from, messageId);
                        send(ack);
                    } else if ("ack".equals(messageType.toString())) {
                        // Process Ack
                        handleAckReceipt(jsonObject);
                    } else if ("nack".equals(messageType.toString())) {
                        // Process Nack
                        handleNackReceipt(jsonObject);
                    } else {
                        logger.log(Level.WARNING,
                                "Unrecognized message type (%s)",
                                messageType.toString());
                    }
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error parsing JSON " + json, e);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Couldn't send echo.", e);
                }
            }
        }, new PacketTypeFilter(Message.class));

        // Log all outgoing packets
        connection.addPacketInterceptor(new PacketInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void interceptPacket(Packet packet) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Sent: {0}", packet.toXML());
            }
        }, new PacketTypeFilter(Message.class));

        connection.login(username, password);
    }

    public void writeToFile(String name, String regId) throws IOException {
        Map<String, String> regIdMap = readFromFile();
        regIdMap.put(name, regId);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                REG_ID_STORE, false)));
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : regIdMap.entrySet()) {
            out.println(entry.getKey() + "," + entry.getValue());
        }
        out.println(name + "," + regId);
        out.close();

    }

    public Map<String, String> readFromFile() {
    Map<String, String> regIdMap = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(REG_ID_STORE));
        String regIdLine = "";
        regIdMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        while ((regIdLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] regArr = regIdLine.split(",");
            regIdMap.put(regArr[0], regArr[1]);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
    }
        return regIdMap;
    }

 public static void main(String [] args) {
    final String userName = "Sender ID" + "@gcm.googleapis.com";
    final String password = "Server key";

    SmackCcsClient ccsClient = new SmackCcsClient();

    try {
      ccsClient.connect(userName, password);
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was looking at this example a few days ago. It doesn't look too bad to implement in my code. However, I see that there is no authentication as far as the connection goes with Firebase Cloud Messaging. If you look at this link  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#connecting      it says that there is some communication between your "app server" and Firebase CCS in order to authenticate the connection. It says there must be SASL plain mechanism for it to work. I dont see where that takes place in the code above. @RileyMacDonald

Comment: Also, Riley. Why do we have to run our server via the command prompt. Can't you just compile and run from your IDE, since the server code resides in your IDE. Perhaps is cause that's just the way you run your code through command prompt? @RileyMacDonald

Comment: There is a connection being made between this server and FCM. Near the end of the code you will see where the connection is finally made:                 ccsClient.connect(userName, password); Also I just chose to run the server through the CMD for testing but you can implement it however you want

Comment: @RileyMacDonald  Wow! Thank you so much gentle internet soul. You have saved me hours and hours of tedious work. Thank you, Thank you!