# Ejabberd isolate group of users

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I want to isolate some users of Ejabberd. I mean that only specific users within a list (in database, json, or any other format) can interact (chat, subscribe, etc). Is this possible by developing a plugin or I need to hack Ejabbed code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible by developing a plugin. You can for example, use the `filter_packet` hook in ejabberd.

You can find the list of hooks on [ejabberd documentation site for developers](http://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/hooks/).

Comment: filter_packet does the job. In case somebody else want more details here is a simple example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939879/how-to-filter-messages-in-ejabberd